# Not sure how to specify data type for SQL COMMAND

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a create statement in SQL Workshop

not sure what the error is, I tried some adjustments after community feedback, but it seems the issue is in the creation of the table? Not too sure.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 

(
Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR2(25),
Customer_Age,
Customer_City VARCHAR2(20)

);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City )
SELECT 1, 'Simon Li',21,'New York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'Richard Andrew',34,'San Diego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'Catherine Wong',34,'Tuscon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'Marie',28,'Tuscon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 'Bob Richard',27,'San Diego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
```

Error log / Results

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057


3. Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
4. Customer_Name VARCHAR2(25),
5. Customer_Age,
6. Customer_City VARCHAR2(20)
7. );
```

Comment: the semi colon at the end of the insert is missing, typo?

Comment: Use apostrophe, not double quotes, for strings in oracle

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Simon Li'`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. odd column names like `"Odd column name...?"`.

Comment: is this oracle database or mysql?

Comment: @kevinsky take a look at the first three chars of all the error codes

Comment: thanks for the advice , its on the oracle getting started test database page, I'm still getting errors on line 500 but I only have a handful of lines, I think I am missing something big here..

Comment: Specify customer age as an int etc..

Comment: As @CaiusJard said, `customer_age` needs a datatype. When you've fixed that, your `insert` can't end with `union all`.

Comment: In the original version of your question, the problem was that you had an `insert` statement with five `values` clauses, which is invalid because the syntax only supports one. Then in later edits you removed the datatype for the `customer_age` column and switched to an `insert ... select ... union all` syntax which is invalid because it ends with `union all`. Please clarify what the current issue is, including the latest error message.

Comment: Aside from all the syntax issues being addressed by other, I'd ask why you are storing CUSTOMER_AGE.  A person's age changes daily.  Well, annually, if you only consider full years.  In any event, that value will eventually become incorrect with the simple passing of time.  Instead, you should be storing the date of birth.  With that you can always correctly calculate age at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you specify a data type for customer_age**

To insert multiple rows in oracle:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City )
SELECT 1,'Simon Li',21,'New York ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Richard Andrew',34,'San Diego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 ...
SELECT 5,'Bob Richard',27,'San Diego'
```

- Use ' for strings. " are for case sensitive column names with spaces, weird chars etc
- you cannot use the VALUES keyword multiple times. UNION ALL several queries that select constants from dual instead

If you're using a sequence for your id you might need more like:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City )
SELECT idseq.nextval, a, b, c FROM(
  SELECT 'Simon Li' AS A,21 AS B,'New York ' AS C FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Richard Andrew',34,'San Diego' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 ...
  SELECT 'Bob Richard',27,'San Diego'
)X
```

Comment: what is DUAL ? its the identifier to copy from?

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-dual-table/

Comment: Long story short, unlike in other databases where one can say `select  1 ` to get a constant value of one as a result set, in Oracle you have to always select from some table. Dual is a table that contains a single row and a single column called dummy. People never actually select the contents of dual but if you want a single row of constants like your name your city et cetera in your example, you select from dual because you have to select from something and selecting from a table that has one row means you only get one row of values out

Comment: For a laugh you can mess up your DBAs day by inserting another row into dual. Joking. **Don't actually do it**, things break all over he place because the expectation is that it has one row. If it has more, queries like this will generate too many (duplicated) rows and fail with primary key violations etc.. but it's fun and maybe even helpful to think about why it works and what the consequences are :)

Comment: H'm I am still getting the same error about missing or invalid option at line 500+ , then some refrence to when I create the table, but not showing any specific line that is wrong.

Comment: @jcx3x Did you specify a type for customer age?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of inserting multiple rows into the table is like below

```
 INSERT ALL
      INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
      INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
      INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
    SELECT * FROM dual;
```

In your case

```
INSERT ALL
      INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City ) VALUES (1,'Simon Li',21,'New York')
      INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City ) VALUES (2,'Richard Andrew',34,'San Diego')
      INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City ) VALUES (3,'Catherine Wong',34,'Tuscon')
      INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City ) VALUES (4,'Marie',28,'Tuscon')
      INTO CUSTOMER (Customer_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_Age,Customer_City ) VALUES (5,'Bob Richard',27,'San Diego')
    SELECT * FROM dual;
```

and also you are missing the data type for column Customer_Age , Age is number max of 3 digits so we can declare it as 
NUMBER(3)

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 

(
Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR2(25),
Customer_Age NUMBER(3),
Customer_City VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Comment: yea no need to add ; after each statement

Comment: Oracle SQL doesn't have a `;` character.